# How do I raise HttpResponseForbidden in CreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried this in perform_create method:

```
if not user.is_active:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

But no errors occured, it still responsing 201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this construct instead:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied  
# You can also use Django's PermissionDenied here; DRF handles that nicely
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

if not user.is_active:
    raise PermissionDenied
```

`PermissionDenied` is defined as follows:

```
class PermissionDenied(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
    default_detail = _('You do not have permission to perform this action.')
    default_code = 'permission_denied'
```

You might be wondering how raising an exception inside the `View` returns a the appropriate `HttpResponse`. DRF's `APIView` has a nifty `handle_exception` method that uses the `exception_handler` function (seen below) that does this magic:

```
def exception_handler(exc, context):
    """
    Returns the response that should be used for any given exception.

    By default we handle the REST framework `APIException`, and also
    Django's built-in `Http404` and `PermissionDenied` exceptions.

    Any unhandled exceptions may return `None`, which will cause a 500 error
    to be raised.
    """
    if isinstance(exc, Http404):
        exc = exceptions.NotFound()
    # This is how both PermissionDenied classes are made to work
    elif isinstance(exc, PermissionDenied):  
        exc = exceptions.PermissionDenied()

    if isinstance(exc, exceptions.APIException):
        headers = {}
        if getattr(exc, 'auth_header', None):
            headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = exc.auth_header
        if getattr(exc, 'wait', None):
            headers['Retry-After'] = '%d' % exc.wait

        if isinstance(exc.detail, (list, dict)):
            data = exc.detail
        else:
            data = {'detail': exc.detail}

        set_rollback()
        return Response(data, status=exc.status_code, headers=headers)

    return None
```

Clarification:

`PermissionDenied` is an exception; you need to `raise` it not `return` it

Comment: @ДмитрийСажнев Have you modified the default `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` in DRF? Is this key set in your `settings.py`? -  `settings.EXCEPTION_HANDLER`

Comment: Post your full source code here; there might be something missing from the snippet you have shared

Comment: No I haven't change EXCEPTION_HANDLER. This is the code of the view class - https://pastebin.com/raw/4G0urGPU

Comment: You need to `raise` exceptions; not `return`